# Como carregar JSON no MySQL, incluindo campos especificos do JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Será que alguém me pode ajudar numa dúvida que me anda a massacrar?

Primeiro, estou a  tentar carregar este JSON para o MySQL

```
{
    "business_id": "fNGIbpazjTRdXgwRY_NIXA",
    "full_address": "1201 Washington Ave\nCarnegie, PA 15106",
    "hours": {

    },
    "open": true,
    "categories": ["Bars",
                   "American (Traditional)",
                   "Nightlife",
                   "Lounges",
                   "Restaurants"],
    "city": "Carnegie",
    "review_count": 5,
    "name": "Rocky's Lounge",
    "neighborhoods": [],
    "longitude": -80.084941599999993,
    "state": "PA",
    "stars": 4.0,
    "latitude": 40.396468800000001,
    "attributes": {
        "Alcohol": "full_bar",
        "Noise Level": "average",
        "Music": {
            "dj": false,
            "background_music": true,
            "karaoke": false,
            "live": false,
            "video": false,
            "jukebox": false
        },
        "Attire": "casual",
        "Ambience": {
            "romantic": false,
            "intimate": false,
            "touristy": false,
            "hipster": false,
            "divey": false,
            "classy": false,
            "trendy": false,
            "upscale": false,
            "casual": false
        },
        "Good for Kids": true,
        "Wheelchair Accessible": false,
        "Good For Dancing": false,
        "Delivery": false,
        "Coat Check": false,
        "Smoking": "no",
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true,
        "Take-out": false,
        "Price Range": 2,
        "Outdoor Seating": false,
        "Takes Reservations": false,
        "Waiter Service": true,
        "Caters": false,
        "Good For": {
            "dessert": false,
            "latenight": false,
            "lunch": false,
            "dinner": false,
            "brunch": false,
            "breakfast": false
        },
        "Parking": {
            "garage": false,
            "street": false,
            "validated": false,
            "lot": false,
            "valet": false
        },
        "Has TV": true,
        "Good For Groups": true
    },
    "type": "business"
}
```

E estou a usar o seguinte código

```
<?php
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost:118;dbname=mydb", "root", "1234");
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('c:\yelp_academic_dataset_business.json');

ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get the employee details
$idBusiness = $data['business_id'];
$name = $data['name'];
$neighborhoods = $data['neighborhoods'];
$full_address = $data['full_address'];
$city = $data['city'];
$state = $data['state'];
$latitude = $data['latitude'];
$longitude = $data['longitude'];
$stars = $data['stars'];
$review_count = $data['review_count'];
$open = $data['open'];
$procedure = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO business(business_id, name, neighborhoods, full_address, city, state, latitude, longitude, stars, review_count, open)
VALUES('$idBusiness', '$name', '$neighborhoods', '$full_address', '$city', '$state', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$stars', '$review_count', '$open')");
$procedure -> execute(); 
?>
```

Está-me a dar erro no business_id, refere que não consegue inserir, será que está alguma coisa mal no código? ou será no modelo relacional que está o erro?
o erro é o seguinte:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'business_id'
>   in 'field list'' in C:\wamp\www\Yelp_mysql_Business.php on line 50

---

Segundo, tenho 2 tabelas no modelo relacional com o nome, "*atributos complexos*" que contem o id e a Designaçao e "atributos simples" que contem o id, designação e valor.

Queria uma maneira de conseguir guardar no campo designaçao da tabela *atributos complexos* o valor "good_for", "music" etc... que se desdobram em *atributos simples* como no caso da "music", dj, karaoke, etc.

Só que com o código em cima só me permite guardar o valor do JSON e não os atributos mesmo.

Por exemplo para os attributes não dá para carregar assim para o modelo relacional pelo que tive de criar 2 tabelas relacionadas com a tabela Business, "Atributos Complexos" que são aqueles que possuem vários atributos dentro deste como é o caso de Music, Ambience, e "Atributos Simples" como são o caso de alcohol, noise level. Nos atributos simples criei 2 campos, designação e valor, o que se traduz em alcohol ser a designação e full bar o valor. A minha dúvida é como partir os dados de modo a que alcohol e estes atributos simples sejam carregados para o campo designação na tabela "atributos Simples" no MySQL.

Este é o meu modelo relacional, existem outros JSON como Tip, Review, User e Check-in, mas sabendo como se carrega para o business e como se resolve o problema dos atributos depois para as restantes já conseguia fazer.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Alguém me pode ajudar por favor, é importante.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Ao ler, parece que você tem duas perguntas - uma sobre o carregamento de dados JSON e inserindo-os no MySQL - e outra sobre o modelo das suas tabelas. É bem provável, porém, que não entendi bem a(s) pergunta(s).

Comment: Você diz que te dá um erro, que não consegue inserir - qual é o erro exato? Poderia editar sua pergunta com o texto exato?

Comment: É possivel carregar imagens? senão mostrava o modelo relacional que criei baseado no JSON.

Comment: É possível sim - [veja a ajuda aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), lá em baixo onde diz *Imagens*. Também no editor, creio que tem uma fotinha que pode clicar para abrir um meio de adicionar imagem.

Comment: Muito obrigado, penso que agora com esta informação já se torna perceptível o que pretendo, se alguém me pudesse ajudar por favor, é mesmo muito importante.

Comment: @Gonçalo você poderia [edit] a pergunta e remover a segunda parte que parece ser uma pergunta bem diferente? Você pode fazê-la em separado em uma nova pergunta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O erro que você está recebendo:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'business_id' in 'field list'' in C:\wamp\www\Yelp_mysql_Business.php on line 50"

É por causa dessa linha aqui:

```
$procedure = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO business(business_id, name,
 neighborhoods, full_address, city, state, latitude, longitude, stars,
 review_count, open)
VALUES('$idBusiness', '$name', '$neighborhoods', '$full_address', '$city',
 '$state', '$latitude', '$longitude', '$stars', '$review_count', '$open')");
```

Veja que a primeira linha está usando o **business_id** como nome da coluna, porém o nome da coluna é **idBusiness**. Creio que simplesmente foi uma confusão/conflito entre o nome do ID no JSON e no MySQL.

Então modifique seu SQL para ser assim:

```
INSERT INTO business(idBusiness, name, ... )
VALUES('$idBusiness', '$name', ... )
```

Comment: Correu tudo, mas fui ver ao mysql e nada foi inserido :/

Comment: Nada foi inserido, alguém tem ideia do que poderá estar mal? e Em relação à segunda pergunta alguém me pode ajudar? Obrigado